# Node.JS Sharp library - write after end error

Tags: node.js

I have the following code:

```
var express = require('express');
var request = require('request');
var sharp = require('sharp');
var app = express();

var transformer = sharp()
        .resize(100, 100)
        .crop(sharp.gravity.north)
        .on('error', function(err) {
                console.log('ERR');
                console.log(err);
        });


app.get('/test', function(req, res) {
        var url = 'http://i.ytimg.com/vi/tntOCGkgt98/maxresdefault.jpg';
        request(url).pipe(transformer).pipe(res);
});

var server = app.listen(3000, function() {
        var host = server.address().address;
        var port = server.address().port;
        console.log('Listening at http://%s:%s', host, port);
});
```

The first time I run it it works fine. The second time I run it I get [Error: write after end], which is emitted in the on('error') in the transformer stream.

If I just do

```
request(url).pipe(res);
```

It works fine, so it's only when you include the .pipe(transformer) bit.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You create Duplex (Readable and Writable) stream (transformer) and it's available for different readable streams (request). When you pipe to the transformer stream it gets closed and later you are trying to pipe to the same closed stream again.

```
var transformer = sharp();
var stream = require('stream');

// transformer is a stream
console.log("transformer instanceof stream.Duplex - ", transformer instanceof stream.Duplex); // true


// just a simple streams example
var readable = new stream.Readable();
var writable = new stream.Writable();

readable.push("data");
readable.push(null);

writable._write = function (chunk, encoding, done) {
  console.log("Writable stream received data: ", chunk.toString());
  done();
};

var _saved_original_end_method = writable.end;
// redefining end method just to see if it's executed
writable.end = function () {
  console.log("Ending writable stream");

  _saved_original_end_method.apply(this, arguments);
};

// first piping finished successfully
readable.pipe(writable);

var anotherReadableStream = new stream.Readable();

setTimeout(function () {
  // this will cause an exception
  anotherReadableStream.push("another data sample");
  anotherReadableStream.push(null);
  anotherReadableStream.pipe(writable);
}, 1000);
```

Result:

```
transformer instanceof stream.Duplex -  true
Writable stream received data:  data
Ending writable stream
events.js:85
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
            ^
Error: write after end
```

Comment: So...the solution is to create a new `transformer` for each `request()`, is what you were going to suggest, right? ;-)

Comment: Thanks, helps to clarify things. I just put the transformer declaration inside the scope of the function so it gets recreated for each request - does the job nicely.